# ElasticSearch [6.5] fetching multiple records execution time issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch about 2.5 million records from elastic search using elastic search's Java High Level Client. Which is taking too much time (15 to 22 minutes based on number of records) to fetch all the record using scroll API as it has a limitation of fetch 10,000 record in one request. I tried sliced scroll also but that is taking more time than normal scroll. Following is my assumption about sliced scroll API:

1. I divided my scroll request into five slices. Which creates 5 requests.
2. I send 5 request in different threads.
3. Because every sliced scroll request is an individual request. I guess for each sliced scroll request first it fetches all the records (2.5 million) then filters out the records which belongs to that particular slice.
   Which is resulting in more time.

Can anyone tell me more efficient way to fetch all the records.

Comment: "I guess for each sliced scroll request first it fetches all the records (2.5 million) then filters out the records which belongs to that particular slice." This is how a limit + offset works but not a scroll. Generally, what is your bottleneck? Is it the Elasticsearch queries or maybe something in your Java app? Also 10K docs per request might not be the ideal size

Comment: Because I can fetch 10,000 records per request. For that I need to make 250 request to fetch 2.5 million users. One request takes about 3.4 to 6 seconds to get the records. So to fetch all 2.5 million records it takes time.

Comment: This doesn't relate to what I have said. 1) Maybe a smaller batch size works better; there is normally a sweetspot and it's not necessarily the largest value. 2) Is it really the Elasticsearch query that is your bottleneck? Is the 3.4 to 6s the `took` from the query?